# INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI Spotify

Tags: client, client-server, spotify, spotify-app

I tried callback and edited my Spotify config and Spotify development uri but none if it works.

const redirectUri = "https://spotify-clone-69752.web.app/callback/";

Spotify Redirect URI https://spotify-clone-69752.web.app/callback/

I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist the URI in your Spotify Application Dashboard -> Edit Settings -> Redirect URI's: developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications